# Find superior element in html with Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, web, xpath, identifier

I have the following html code:

```
<tr id="id that I want to obtain via title">
   <td class="icon">
       <span class="greenArrowIcon pid-1-arrowSmall"></span>
   </td>
   <td class="bold left noWrap elp">
       <a href="..." title="title that I have obtained">
           TITLE
       </a>
       <MORE CODE>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and I know that the tag title `title="title that I have obtained"` are always the same, but the id `id="id that I want to obtain viva title"` could change, is strange that changes, but could.
So, my question is: How can I find the `id` via the `title` ? I think the problem is that the `title` tag is inside (an inferior jerarchy) from the `id` that I want to solve it.

I am using Selenium, and this is the code to solve the title and get the web element:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[title^='title that I have obtained']")
```

Is it possible do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the desired `id` attribute value you can use the following XPath locator:

```py
tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//a[@title='title that I have obtained']]")
id = tr.get_attribute("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Already @Prophet answered in a good way but I want to show you other ways to find the same element.

**Using `parent` function**:

```
 //a[@title='title that I have obtained']//parent::td//..
```

```
 //a[@title='title that I have obtained']//..//parent::tr
```

**Using `ancestor` function**:

```
//a[@title='title that I have obtained']//ancestor::tr
```